# How to get a field on a control group

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to get access to a field on a website & write an answer to it. I cannot for the life of me figure out it's name or how to reference it. I can see it's sitting on a form. There are 3 fields on it, I want the first one. There don't seem to be any id's to work with. I've tried looping through getting it to print tag names and such I;m using VBA to open the webpage, etc.

This is the HTML:

```htm
<ng-form class="form ng-pristine ng-valid" name="policySearchForm">
   <div class="gw-control-group-wrapper">
      <div class="form-item select-form-fli form-item-grid-fli ng-isolate-scope" model="policySearchRequestView.policyNumber" label="Policy Number" gw-pl-ctrl-group="">
         <div class="gw-control-group" aria-hidden="false" ng-class="{ 'gw-error': showError(), 'gw-inline-control-group': inline, 'gw-control-group': !inline, 'gw-control-group-focused' : focused, 'required-fli': model.aspects.required }" ng-show="isVisible()">
            <!-- ngIf: label -->
            <label title="" class="ng-scope gw-control-label" ng-class="{'gw-control-inline-label': inline, 'gw-control-label': !inline}" ng-if="label">
               <span class="ng-binding">
                  Policy Number
                  <!-- Information icon for Useful Hints -->
                  <!-- ngIf: usefulHint -->
               </span>
               <span class="gw-required-asterisk ng-hide" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="(model.aspects.required &amp;&amp; !readonly) || (showAsterisk &amp;&amp; !readonly &amp;&amp; label === 'Date Of Birth')">*</span>
            </label>
            <!-- end ngIf: label -->
            <div class="gw-controls" ng-class="{'gw-inline-controls': inline, 'gw-controls': !inline}">
               <ng-transclude>
                  <input tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" type="text" ng-model="policySearchRequestView.policyNumber.value" ng-keypress="($event.which === 13)?searchPolicies():0">
               </ng-transclude>
               <div class="gw-inline-messages" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="!readonly">
                  <!-- ngRepeat: errorMessage in model.aspects.validationMessages track by $index -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ngIf: policySearchRequestView.IsPersonalPolicy === 'true' -->
      <div class="form-item-grid-fli ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-if="policySearchRequestView.IsPersonalPolicy === 'true'" model="policySearchRequestView.firstName" label="First Name" gw-pl-ctrl-group="">
         <div class="gw-control-group" aria-hidden="false" ng-class="{ 'gw-error': showError(), 'gw-inline-control-group': inline, 'gw-control-group': !inline, 'gw-control-group-focused' : focused, 'required-fli': model.aspects.required }" ng-show="isVisible()">
            <!-- ngIf: label -->
            <label title="" class="ng-scope gw-control-label" ng-class="{'gw-control-inline-label': inline, 'gw-control-label': !inline}" ng-if="label">
               <span class="ng-binding">
                  First Name
                  <!-- Information icon for Useful Hints -->
                  <!-- ngIf: usefulHint -->
               </span>
               <span class="gw-required-asterisk ng-hide" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="(model.aspects.required &amp;&amp; !readonly) || (showAsterisk &amp;&amp; !readonly &amp;&amp; label === 'Date Of Birth')">*</span>
            </label>
            <!-- end ngIf: label -->
            <div class="gw-controls" ng-class="{'gw-inline-controls': inline, 'gw-controls': !inline}">
               <ng-transclude>
                  <input tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" type="text" ng-model="policySearchRequestView.firstName.value" ng-keypress="($event.which === 13)?searchPolicies():0">
                  <!--<div class="exact-match-fli">-->
                  <!--<div class="gw-control-label">-->
                  <!--{{'agent.views.policy-landing.Exact Match' | translate}}-->
                  <!--<input type="checkbox"-->
                  <!--ng-model="policySearchRequest.isFirstNameExact"-->
                  <!--class="gw-check"-->
                  <!--id="firstNamePolicyCheckboxLabel{{$index}}">-->
                  <!--<label class="gw-checkbox" id="firstNamePolicyCheckboxLabel" for="firstNamePolicyCheckboxLabel{{$index}}"></label>-->
                  <!--</div>-->
                  <!--</div>-->
               </ng-transclude>
               <div class="gw-inline-messages" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="!readonly">
                  <!-- ngRepeat: errorMessage in model.aspects.validationMessages track by $index -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end ngIf: policySearchRequestView.IsPersonalPolicy === 'true' -->
      <!-- ngIf: policySearchRequestView.IsPersonalPolicy == 'true' -->
      <div class="form-item-grid-fli full-width-input-fli ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-if="policySearchRequestView.IsPersonalPolicy == 'true'" model="policySearchRequestView.lastName" label="Last Name" gw-pl-ctrl-group="">
         <div class="gw-control-group" aria-hidden="false" ng-class="{ 'gw-error': showError(), 'gw-inline-control-group': inline, 'gw-control-group': !inline, 'gw-control-group-focused' : focused, 'required-fli': model.aspects.required }" ng-show="isVisible()">
            <!-- ngIf: label -->
            <label title="" class="ng-scope gw-control-label" ng-class="{'gw-control-inline-label': inline, 'gw-control-label': !inline}" ng-if="label">
               <span class="ng-binding">
                  Last Name
                  <!-- Information icon for Useful Hints -->
                  <!-- ngIf: usefulHint -->
               </span>
               <span class="gw-required-asterisk ng-hide" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="(model.aspects.required &amp;&amp; !readonly) || (showAsterisk &amp;&amp; !readonly &amp;&amp; label === 'Date Of Birth')">*</span>
            </label>
            <!-- end ngIf: label -->
            <div class="gw-controls" ng-class="{'gw-inline-controls': inline, 'gw-controls': !inline}">
               <ng-transclude>
                  <input tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" type="text" ng-model="policySearchRequestView.lastName.value" ng-keypress="($event.which === 13)?searchPolicies():0">
                  <!--<div class="exact-match-fli">-->
                  <!--<div class="gw-control-label">-->
                  <!--{{'agent.views.policy-landing.Exact Match' | translate}}-->
                  <!--<input type="checkbox"-->
                  <!--ng-model="policySearchRequest.isLastNameExact"-->
                  <!--class="gw-check"-->
                  <!--id="lastNamePolicyCheckboxLabel{{$index}}">-->
                  <!--<label class="gw-checkbox" id="lastNamePolicyCheckboxLabel" for="lastNamePolicyCheckboxLabel{{$index}}"></label>-->
                  <!--</div>-->
                  <!--</div>-->
               </ng-transclude>
               <div class="gw-inline-messages" aria-hidden="false" ng-show="!readonly">
                  <!-- ngRepeat: errorMessage in model.aspects.validationMessages track by $index -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end ngIf: policySearchRequestView.IsPersonalPolicy == 'true' -->
      <!-- ngIf: policySearchRequestView.IsPersonalPolicy === 'false' -->
   </div>
</ng-form>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction how I can determine how to reference it or the input boxes name?

Comment: quick comment, sorry the field i want will be/relate to the Policy Number. First Name & Last Name comes after it. not sure the exact name but it s/b similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the first input box for your shown HTML. I would combine a CSS attribute = value selector with element selector to target

```
input[ng-model='policySearchRequestView.policyNumber.value']
```

Assuming using IE:

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[ng-model='policySearchRequestView.policyNumber.value']")
```

You can use same syntax but replacing attribute value with

```
policySearchRequestView.firstName.value
```

and

```
policySearchRequestView.lastName.value
```

for the others.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I'll run it tomorrow at the office. QuerySelector is not syntax i'm familiar with. I'm assuming I can assign a value to it? Normally I've had something like HTMLinput.value = "sometext"   where HTMLinput was an element set in the VBA earlier, maybe looped thru in a collection.

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) returns a single node. The first element that matches the css selector specified inside the (). querySelectorAll returns a nodeList, a collection of all matching elements which you loop the .Length of (you can't For Each over it - it will crash Excel). And yes, in this instance you can assign a value to it with .value = "".

Comment: Outstanding! I ran it and worked like a charm first go! Thank you very much! I would not have looked at querySelector so I think this will be a good new tool for me to learn to use.

Comment: It is a method that gives you access to some powerful and flexible syntax.

Comment: Well, i had one more thing to do on that page & I grabbed that item my old way using a little for each loop, confirmed it work, but then applied your way & that one is working too & a touch quicker since I'm not looping through anything, so again thank you very much. I'm feeling pretty good today, making progress on the project!